# Bypass Chrome OS setup

Tags: google-chrome-os

After enabling developer mode and debugging options I have access to root console on tty2. I can kill the session manager or chrome but those just start again.

How do I bypass chrome setup screen?

UPDATE: When I left the system on for the night and it switched to demo mode. Not mutch to play around there. Might be interesting for someone.

Comment: So what are you actually trying to accomplish? What do you hope to gain by bypassing setup?

Comment: Mostly I want to play around, test if the hardware works properly and learn how Google set up the drivers for graphics (Mali).